# Puedo dejar una variable vacía y después trabajar con ella?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

En una parte de mi código necesito que, en caso de no devolver ningún valor se establezca el valor de una variable como vacía para después trabajar con ella, no se si me explico pero adjunto mi código, espero eso ayude.

```
    try:
    enmedioa = datos[(datos[1]<0.00001170) & (datos[2]>0.00001170)]
    enmediobajo = enmedioa[0].iloc[0]
    print(enmediobajo)

    enmedioah = datos[datos[1]>0.00001215]
    enmedioch = enmedioah[enmedioah[3]<0.00001215]
    enmedioalto = enmedioch[0].iloc[0]
    print(enmedioalto)
except:
    print("Alguno de los dos valores no existe")
    enmedioalto = None
    enmediobajo = None
```

Como ven, lo intente con el tipo de dato none pero no sirve para lo que necesito porque mas adelante utilizare las variables para realizar operaciones

```
valores = [enmediobajo, enmedioalto, apertura, cierre]
menor= valores[0]
for i in valores:
    if i < menor:
        menor = i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí es necesario asígnale un valor a las variables, porque con el valor asignado es que Python identifica lo que es una variable.

Para evitar que te salga error en la declaracion if en el caso que el valor sea None, podrías poner otra declaración if que compruebe si ese elemento iterado es diferente a None. Algo como esto:

```py
for i in valores:
    if i != None:
        if i < menor:
            menor = i
```